# How to pass HEX character with no corresponding ASCII to a C program as input

Tags: buffer-overflow, c

Your first answer would be to use perl or python and pipe the input to the C program, but unfortunately the variable I want to input is not taking the value from argument of the C program, rather it interactively prompts the user to input a value.

My buffer has a size of 8 bytes and anything more than 8 bytes over write the previous variable [which is exactly what I want] and I want that variable to be over written with the value 1335. The variable to be over written is b and it is of int type. So converting 1335 to hex gives me 537 and I have to overwrite the buffer with 8 a's and then the hex 37, 05, 00 and 00. To overwrite with these values, I should be giving the ASCII corresponding to 37, 05 and 00 in the user input. As 05 and 00 in ASCII are control characters, I am unable to input the same using keyboard. Is there any way to input the ASCII of these values to the user input?

Desktop : Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: what terminal and OS/desktop environment are you using? How to interactively input arbitrary characters depends on the terminal and desktop environment.

Comment: @lie I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: The values can be input as octal characters by holding down the <alt> key and using the keypad to input the digits

Comment: In that case, should I be giving the entire input as octal?

Comment: that depends.  are all the input characters of the non-printing range?   Other wise, you can simply use the <alt>octal char method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by escaping the null character with Ctrl+ @

Comment: search this site for "*shellcode*" which will explain the various requirements and a number of helpful tips to accomplish this properly.

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically solve the issue, you can use [expect](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/expect1.html) in a shell script.

Comment: could you expand on how that is expected to generate a character in stdin that the C program can read using something like `getchar()`?